# Value for Non-Nullable System.DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

The following code works fine for a nullable DateTime :

```
lastSync = syncHistsQuery.Max(m => m.Value);
```

Why does the same code not work for a non-nullable DateTime ? Here is the error :

```
'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)
```

Do I have to change DateTime to a Nullable DateTime in the database ? Is there a different way to write the code for non-nullable DateTimes ?

Here is the entire function in case it helps :

```
public static DateTime GetMaxSyncDateTime()
{
    DateTime lastSync = DateTime.MinValue;
    using (var db = new CarbonContext())
    {
        var syncHistsQuery = from s in db.SyncHistories
                                 select s.SyncHistDateTime;

        lastSync = syncHistsQuery.Max(m => m.Value);
    }
    return lastSync;
}
```

Comment: Try just: `syncHistsQuery.Max();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Nullable" `DateTime?` is in fact a *syntax sugar* for

```
  Nullable<DateTime>
```

which has two properies

```
  public Boolean HasValue
  public DateTime Value
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx

`DateTime` itself has a lot of properies but no `Value` property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime(v=vs.100).aspx

Since `DateTime` implements `IComparable<DateTime>` just use `Max()`:

```
lastSync = syncHistsQuery.Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because non nullable `DateTime` doesn't have a `Value` property.You use

```
lastSync = syncHistsQuery.Max();
```

If you are working with `DateTimes`.

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` doesn't have a `.Value` property, that is something from `Nullable<T>`.

You can just do:

```
lastSync = syncHistsQuery.Max(m => m);
```

Or, as pointed out, you can shorten it to:

```
lastSync = syncHistsQuery.Max();
```

Comment: `m => m` has no sense - better is overload with no arguments.